# Why do I keep blowing this current shunt amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, dc-motor, current-measurement, common-mode, shunt

I'm using an INA293B3-Q1 current shunt amplifier in the standard high-side configuration as shown below.  The supply is a variable DC power supply (0-20V).  Rsense = 1 mOhm.  And, the load is a brushed DC motor.  At 12V, I ran the motor at varying loads to create currents between 5A and 25A.  The circuit worked like a charm.  Twice now, I gradually increase the voltage to 14V, and the amplifier chip goes up in smoke.

After these failures, I switched to low-side configuration and no problems.  Unfortunatley, I really need to run this on the high side, because I'll be using another one of these circuits to measure phase current on a brushless motor.

I'm guessing it is related to a ground offset, or common-mode issue?  I should also mention that there is an SSR in between the supply and the current shunt.  It was on constantly during all of my testing, so I do not believe my issue is related to inductive kick-back.

[image]

Comment: This long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore it has been moved to chat and should be continued there (link below). --- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once, any further comments posted here which try to clarify and understand the question, might be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat, please!** When someone has got enough information from the chat to post an answer, then please do that. Any factual updates to the question which are decided during the chat, should be made via an edit to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Since comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126346/discussion-on-question-by-gtetil-why-do-i-keep-blowing-this-current-shunt-amplif).